# How can I catch an error when I use uigetfile ? [MATLAB]

Tags: matlab, error-handling

I have this sentence `colorImage = imread(uigetfile('*.jpg;*.tif;*.png;*.gif'));` where I choose an image from my computer.

The problem is that when I press cancel button an error appears. How can I catch the error when I press cancel?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Matlab's [try and catch](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/try.html) mechanism.
Example:

```
try
colorImage = imread(uigetfile('*.jpg;*.tif;*.png;*.gif'));
catch ME
  if (strcmp(ME.identifier,'MATLAB:imagesci:imread:badImageSourceDatatype'))
      %do something
  end  
end
```

Comment: The identifier was `MATLAB:imagesci:imread:badImageSourceDatatype` . Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: When used without specifying the output parameters (as in the OP instruction), the function uigetfile return only the filename therefore if the selected file s neither in the current directory nor in a folder in the MatLab path `imread` will not be able to find the file. More "dangerous" is a file with the selected name does exist in the current folder or in the a folder in the MatLAb path, that file  will be read instead of the selected one.

Answer (score 1):

When used without specifying the out parameters (as in you instruction), the function `uigetfile` return only the `filename`.

If you select an image file which is neither in the current directory nor in a folder in the MatLab `path`, the `imread` function will not be able to find the image file; in that case you have to provide `imread` with the complete filename (path + filename).

You have then better to split the instruction:

- get the image filename with `uigetfile`
- check for selection abort: you do it by checking `class` of the output variable `filename`

  - in case of file selection the `class` of `filename` will be `char`
  - in case of selection abort, it will be `double` since `uigetfile` in that case returns `0`
- in case of a valid selection, build the image full filename with `fullfile`
- in case of selection abort, print a message

This is a possible implementation of the above listed steps.

```
% Get the image full file name (path and filename)
[filename,pathname]=uigetfile('*.jpg;*.tif;*.png;*.gif')
% Check for selection abort
if(strcmp(class(filename),'char'))
   % If an image has been selected, create the image full filename
   the_img=fullfile(pathname,filename);
   % Read the image
   colorImage = imread(the_img)
else
   % If the image selection has been aborted, print a message
   disp('Image selection aborted')
end
```